# Salesforce.com with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, salesforce

I am very new in salesfore and RoR. But I need to design salesforce using visualforce. So I like to Know, Is there any possibility to use ruby on rails inside the salesforce.com website on UI.

If there any possibility to means its very useful to me for design. Your suggestion please..!

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: yeah. correct.. Can you tell me, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the UI for salesforce.com in visualforce ie apex. You can have external website and iframe it inside salesforce.com

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, but I could not understand exactly what you told. Can you please give some clear details about it. if possible can you give some example code here.